# Removing currency format in Crystal Reports pie chart legend

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports for VS2010 and am creating a pie chart report. I can get the  chart to format OK, however I'm having two difficulties:

1. I'm showing the values and the percentages in the legend, however the values are being shown with a currency symbol, which I don't want. I've checked all the chart properties and none of the formats are set to currency.
2. I'd like to display the legend in descending order of percentage. Presently it's being shown in label order.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ideas for #1:

- Try right click chart | Chart Options... | Legend | Show Values - not sure this will work
- Create a formula that converts currency into a number, use this formula in chart instead of currency field

Ideas for #2:

- Select Report | Group Sort Expert... | All | Descending (works in CR v11)

Comment: Thanks @craig:  
1. I already have Show Values checked.  
2. I hadn't seen the Group Sort Expert before, thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately it only seems to work for the sort order of the report itself, not for the chart. I suppose I could hide the legend and output the values in the body of the report, but the legend would be more helpful.

Comment: I experimented a bit more.  I got nothing.  Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, once again I've come to the conclusion that Crystal Reports is a horrible piece of software...

Answer (score 0):

CR isn't THAT horrible.  Well, maybe... ;-)

Anyway, I ran across this in the CR Designer when a user called in a panic about a report that someone else had developed.  The only format choices the designer could get were % or $ - neither were what was specified: just straight count.

I took couple of runs at formatting the legend, right-click chart options, etc. and got nowhere...

In CR Designer, tho', there is  Chart Expert,  with a tab Options.  In the left-hand side of Options, midway, there is a section called "Data points".  In Data points, you can select wx to have labels for each slice, or values, or both.
If you Check Values, you can then select the format for the value.  This will change the format of the legend, also.
Afterwards, you can UN-CHECK Show Value, the legend keeps the format.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but i found it while trying to find a solution(unsuccessful) But did some tinkering and found that if you edit the series occurrences and then show values and then turn values back off for the series it takes away the currency value.

Similar to what was suggested prior with "Data points" just i guess the new way to find it.